# Scan a super method definition from TreeScanner.visitMethodInvocation

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, annotation-processing, java-compiler-api

Given the following class hierarchy

```
public AClass {
  
  String getSomething() { ... }
}
```

```
public BClass extends AClass {
  @Override
  @CustomAnnotation
  String getSomething() { super.getSomething(); }
}
```

In a Gradle project with three sub-project as the following:

- **A** (where AClass is defined)
- **B** (where BClass is defined)
- **processor** (where the annotation processor is defined).

Project **B** has annotation processor dependency for project **processor**

---

I have an annotation processor to visit elements annotated with *@CustomAnnoatition* and I have a tree path scanner:

```
class MyScanner extends TreePathScanner<String, Trees> {
  String result;

  ...

  public String scan(TreePath treePath, Trees trees) {
    super.scan(treePath, trees);
    return result;
  }

  public String visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocationTree node, Trees trees) {
     // field result initialized here
     return super.visitMethodInvocation(node, trees);
  }
}
```

wehere `TreePath` is constructed from the `ExecutableElement` that represents my annotated method, i.e `BClass.getSomething()`, and `Trees` is instantiated from my proceessor's init method:
`Trees.instance(processingEnv);`.

As you can see the method body of *BClass.getSomething()* is just *super.getSomething()* and I would like to initiate an additional tree path scanning on that very method definition. Or with other words I would like to propagate the scanning to the super method element.
How can I do that?

From `visitMethodInvocation` I have acquired the ExecutableElement for the super.getSomething()
and use it get a new TreePath for the scanning, but unfortunately for that element I got back a `null` from the getPath: `trees.getPath(trees.getElement(this.getCurrentPath()))` so this approach does not seem to be working.

---

Note from debugger I have seen that the enclosing `TypeElement`s of the `ExecutablElement`s, that is, `AClass` and `BClass` of `AClass.getSomething()` and `BClass.getSomething()` respectively, are treated somewhat differently as the latter has an explicit source file with an absolute path while the former has only some 'class source' without a real path.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The AST is constructed from the java source file and in your case when compiling `BClass` the java compiler doesn't have access to the source file of `AClass`, it has only access to the (compiled) class file of `AClass`. It probably will work if both `AClass` and `BClass` are within the same project.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I was afraid that's is the case, indeed. I can think of some very ugly hacks to get a path to the super's source file and make it used by the Java compiler API to get an AST.. and not only it'd be an overkill but probably the tree construction would be a redundant step anyway (or the is the compiler API clever enough to not parse that class twice in such a situation? i doubt that..)..